# How to configure WireGuard AllowedIPs to allow local connections and route all other traffic?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, windows-11, wireguard

I am using WireGuard on Windows 11 to connect to a VPN server. I want to allow local connections to my Wi-Fi network, which starts with 192.168.45.1, and route all the rest of the internet traffic through WireGuard. Also, I have noticed something when you have this `::/0` in the AllowedIPs it breaks everything all connections even IPv4 still gets routed to WireGuard even the local ones until you change that to like `::/1`.

I have checked a lot of resources about my problem, including this calculator: 
https://www.procustodibus.com/blog/2021/03/wireguard-allowedips-calculator/

but I am still confused about the best AllowedIPs settings for my scenario.

Here are the three different settings that I have tried:

**First setting: This works partly so Edge won’t use IPv6 with this setting.**

```
AllowedIPs = 1.0.0.0/8, 2.0.0.0/7, 4.0.0.0/6, 8.0.0.0/7, 11.0.0.0/8, 12.0.0.0/6, 16.0.0.0/4, 32.0.0.0/3, 64.0.0.0/3, 96.0.0.0/4, 112.0.0.0/5, 120.0.0.0/6, 124.0.0.0/7, 126.0.0.0/8, 128.0.0.0/3, 160.0.0.0/5, 168.0.0.0/8, 169.0.0.0/9, 169.128.0.0/10, 169.192.0.0/11, 169.224.0.0/12, 169.240.0.0/13, 169.248.0.0/14, 169.252.0.0/15, 169.255.0.0/16, 170.0.0.0/7, 172.0.0.0/12, 172.32.0.0/11, 172.64.0.0/10, 172.128.0.0/9, 173.0.0.0/8, 174.0.0.0/7, 176.0.0.0/4, 192.0.0.0/9, 192.128.0.0/11, 192.160.0.0/13, 192.169.0.0/16, 192.170.0.0/15, 192.172.0.0/14, 192.176.0.0/12, 192.192.0.0/10, 193.0.0.0/8, 194.0.0.0/7, 196.0.0.0/6, 200.0.0.0/5, 208.0.0.0/4, 224.0.0.0/4, ::/1, 8000::/2, c000::/3, e000::/4, f000::/5, f800::/6, fe00::/9, fec0::/10, ff00::/8
```

**Second setting: I just replaced 8000::/2 with 8000::/1, which made Edge work fine with IPv6.**

```
AllowedIPs = 1.0.0.0/8, 2.0.0.0/7, 4.0.0.0/6, 8.0.0.0/7, 11.0.0.0/8, 12.0.0.0/6, 16.0.0.0/4, 32.0.0.0/3, 64.0.0.0/3, 96.0.0.0/4, 112.0.0.0/5, 120.0.0.0/6, 124.0.0.0/7, 126.0.0.0/8, 128.0.0.0/3, 160.0.0.0/5, 168.0.0.0/8, 169.0.0.0/9, 169.128.0.0/10, 169.192.0.0/11, 169.224.0.0/12, 169.240.0.0/13, 169.248.0.0/14, 169.252.0.0/15, 169.255.0.0/16, 170.0.0.0/7, 172.0.0.0/12, 172.32.0.0/11, 172.64.0.0/10, 172.128.0.0/9, 173.0.0.0/8, 174.0.0.0/7, 176.0.0.0/4, 192.0.0.0/9, 192.128.0.0/11, 192.160.0.0/13, 192.169.0.0/16, 192.170.0.0/15, 192.172.0.0/14, 192.176.0.0/12, 192.192.0.0/10, 193.0.0.0/8, 194.0.0.0/7, 196.0.0.0/6, 200.0.0.0/5, 208.0.0.0/4, 224.0.0.0/4, ::/1, 8000::/1, c000::/3, e000::/4, f000::/5, f800::/6, fe00::/9, fec0::/10, ff00::/8
```

**Third setting: I just replaced 128.0.0.0/3 with 128.0.0.0/1, because that’s what WireGuard does when I uncheck the kill switch.**

```
AllowedIPs = 1.0.0.0/8, 2.0.0.0/7, 4.0.0.0/6, 8.0.0.0/7, 11.0.0.0/8, 12.0.0.0/6, 16.0.0.0/4, 32.0.0.0/3, 64.0.0.0/3, 96.0.0.0/4, 112.0.0.0/5, 120.0.0.0/6, 124.0.0.0/7, 126.0.0.0/8, 128.0.0.0/1, 160.0.0.0/5, 168.0.0.0/8, 169.0.0.0/9, 169.128.0.0/10, 169.192.0.0/11, 169.224.0.0/12, 169.240.0.0/13, 169.248.0.0/14, 169.252.0.0/15, 169.255.0.0/16, 170.0.0.0/7, 172.0.0.0/12, 172.32.0.0/11, 172.64.0.0/10, 172.128.0.0/9, 173.0.0.0/8, 174.0.0.0/7, 176.0.0.0/4, 192.0.0.0/9, 192.128.0.0/11, 192.160.0.0/13, 192.169.0.0/16, 192.170.0.0/15, 192.172.0.0/14, 192.176.0.0/12, 192.192.0.0/10, 193.0.0.0/8, 194.0.0.0/7, 196.0.0.0/6, 200.0.0.0/5, 208.0.0.0/4, 224.0.0.0/4, ::/1, 8000::/1, c000::/3, e000::/4, f000::/5, f800::/6, fe00::/9, fec0::/10, ff00::/8
```

**My questions are:**

- Is any of these settings going to leak my internet traffic?
- Is there anything wrong with any of these settings?
- What is the best way to configure AllowedIPs for my use case?